# visual studio 2013 ultimate "invalid pointer" ( Windows phone )

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

i can't run a WindowsPhone project using emulator ,
The problem is : Invalid Pointer
i'm working on :
-Windows Pro 8.1
-Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
i'm trying a lot of updates ... delete VS and install it again ...

Comment: Please provide enough details about your project so that someone can help.

Comment: clean install of the wp8.1 framework.  Clean install of VS.  Clean install of the operating system. New machine.

Comment: @Scott : i creat a new projet for test , nothing special , the same error ! , it's a problem in emulator ...

Comment: 1- Press (HOME+W) and search for "turn windows features on or off"
2- deactivate the hyperV of ur system
3- apply and ur system will restart
4- activate hyperV again